# Cannot launch rails server. Rails::Secrets::MissingKeyError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, secret-key, google-secret-manager

I got a new machine and recently cloned a project I had been working on on my old machine.  However I was surprised to find that I cannot even launch my rails server. Whenever I try I get this error

```
ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/secrets.rb:77:in `handle_missing_key': Missing encryption key to decrypt secrets with. Ask your team for your master key and put it in ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"] (Rails::Secrets::MissingKeyError)
```

What has caused me to be super confused is that in my `config/secret` I have

```
development:
  secret_key_base: xxxxxxxxx

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

In my config/environments/development.rb, I have this right here.

```
  config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
```

I was expecting/understanding that because the `config/secret` already was populated, I'm not sure where or what to do with this here. Does anyone have any ideas? or suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate config for secret_key_base, therefore removing the line `config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` will fix it.